# Set rounded corners and border to background(Not the UITextField) of UISearchBar in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

How can i apply rounded corners and a border to the background of UISearchBar in ios7? I am able to change the background color of the bar.

Something like this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what about `layer.borderColor`, `layer.borderWidth` and `layer.cornerRadius`?

Comment: @ValentinShamardin I dont want it for the text box but i want it for the black portion as seen in the picture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  UISearchBar *searchBar  = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
  searchBar.layer.cornerRadius  = 6;
  searchBar.clipsToBounds       = YES;
  [searchBar.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  [searchBar.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: I achieved this with Swift by writing:
`self. searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 6`
`self. searchBar.clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0):

For making the search bar round rect use this:

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [mySearchBar subviews]) {
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        @try {

            [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            // ignore exception
        }
    }
}
```

For changing background color use this:

```
yourSearchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Use you necessary color.
```